# Querying a multiindexed pandas data frame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multi-index

For a given data frame `df` such as

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'last_name': ['Clinton', 'Clinton', 'Bush', 'Bush', 'Obama'], 'first_name': ['Bill', 'Hillary', 'George Herbert Walker', 'George Walker', 'Barack']}).set_index(['last_name', 'first_name'])
```

I cannot query the dataframe such as

```
df.loc['last_name', :] ... # or
df.xs('last_name') ...
```

because it fails (`KeyError: 'last_name'`). I think it should work as described [in this blog post about a demonstration of simple uses of MultiIndex](https://www.somebits.com/~nelson/pandas-multiindex-slice-demo.html).

What am I missing?

Comment: I think that isn't supported anymore and I've never seen that usage before, normally one passes a tuple/slice for a given level http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#advanced-indexing-with-hierarchical-index, what are you trying to do specifically? Get the index values or the rows associated with a given index value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few options:

Use query, (not as fexible due to column naming restrictions):

```
df.query('last_name == "Clinton"')
```

Use .loc with axis parameter:

```
df.loc(axis=0)["Clinton",:]
```

Use .xs which returns a slice of the dataframe

```
df.xs('Clinton')
```

Use get_level_values with boolean indexing:

```
df[df.index.get_level_values(0) == "Clinton"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your instruction looks for a row's index which is called 'last_name'.   The error tells you that the given index does not exist.

`df.loc['Clinton','Bill']` would return the row corresponding to 'Clinton, Bill'

`df.loc['Clinton',:]` returns rows for any of the Clintons